# python: accessing return value of a decorated function

Tags: python, function, decorator, return-value

I have a directory like the following:

```
my_dir
  |__data
  |   |__fill
  |        |__ old_data.csv
  |        |__new.csv
  |         
  |read.py
```

I have a read.py file that contains this code:

```
import argparse
import os
from config import data_dir
import pandas as pd


def my_func(func):
    def wrapper():
        if any(fname.startswith('gold') for fname in os.listdir(os.path.join(data_dir, 'fill'))):
            parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
            parser.add_argument('--dir')
            args = parser.parse_args()
            if args.dir is None:
                args.dir = input('Enter data directory:')
                directory = args.dir
                path = os.path.join(data_dir, os.path.join(directory, 'new.csv'))
                return path
        return func()
        return wrapper

@my_func
def another_func():
    if not any(fname.startswith('old') for fname in os.listdir(data_dir)):
        path = os.path.join(data_dir, os.path.join(data.dir, 'old_data.csv'))
        data_ = pd.read_csv(path)
        return data_

print(another_func())
```

when I run the above code it returns None, which is okay because there is no dataset starting with the word 'gold', however, what I would have liked to happen was for the print(another_func()) to print the content of the 'old_data.csv' as I thought this is what the decorator function is supposed to do here, namely if the first function is done, run the decorated function.

Comment: Did you mean to ``return func()`` instead?

Comment: Note that the code as-is is definitely wrongly indented. It would fail with a TypeError or SyntaxError. It is much harder for us if we have to guess what you need – please help us help you and provide a [mre].

Comment: clarifying @MisterMiyagi's comment: you need to `return func()` instead of `func()`, otherwise you throw the return value array (you *also* need to return `wrapper` as you currently do

Comment: sorry for the late reply, and thank you for your comments. if i return both func and the wrapper doesn't one become unreachable?, please see the code

Comment: The line ``return wrapper`` needs to be unindentet one level.